# How to pass FCM key and value to a web view in Main Activity?

Tags: android, webview, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android application that loads a URL in the `WebView` , I implemented Firebase notifications Cloud Messaging .

By FCM custom data (key and value) I want to send the url to which carry the `WebView` .

My ask: 
**How I can access the key and value in the  `Activity` where `WebView` created?**

This is my notificatión file class:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Principal.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Formación Alcalá")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentText(messageBody);



    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

And this is my Main Activity:

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(width);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(Principal.this)) {
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //view.reload();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("sms:")) {
                    // magic
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("formacionalcala.es") || Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("paypal.com")) {
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                    return false;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.formacionalcala.es/app/");
    }else{
        // No hay internet asi que muestro un popup para salir de la app.
        NoInternetDialog dialogo = new NoInternetDialog();
        dialogo.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

**I would like to capture the variables sent by FCM from Main activity.**

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: set a broadcast receiver that gets fired when you receive the notification message, and then before sending broadcast just set the message in intent

Comment: @AmanGrover thanks for answering. I have read about boradcast receiver, but i have not found how to modify the URL of webview. How could access to webview in onReceive() method? Thanks.

Comment: when app opened onMessageRecieved called if app closed in launcher activity with getIntent with fcm keyvalue pair details based on that redirect to our screens.but in app closed notification icon is white square and default sound how to fix